# Is it possible to target the last `:latest` image before current the `:latest` image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Fairly new Docker user here.

Say I have several versions of a docker image, with the latest two being `myimg:1.0.0` and `myimg:2.0.0`. `myimg:2.0.0` is also tagged as `myimg:latest`, whereas before that one was created, `myimg:1.0.0` was also tagged as `myimg:latest`.

Is there a way to point to the second-to-last `:latest` tag, without specifying the exact version (i.e. `:1.0.0` in this example)? Or for that matter, is there some history of which image corresponds to `:latest` that one can go through to find a the image that corresponded to `:latest` *N* versions ago?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to run two succeeding versions of an image alongside each other, so the latest and second-to-latest are always used. I know this is possible by specifying the exact versions, but I'm hoping to make use of `:latest` somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:latest` is just a name. There is absolutely nothing special with it. **It only gets updated when the tag of the Docker image you built was `latest` or was omitted.** There is NO guarantee that `:latest` always points to the latest version of an image.

So it's simple to imagine that there's no simple way to get the second last image like git's HEAD~1. The only way you could do it is via version control.

My personal opinion: tag your images with a version tag.

Comment: Thanks @Birkhoff, I was afraid this would be the verdict. I'll resort to version tags then.